# Propagate library dependencies across targets

Tags: c++, scons

TLDR: Suppose that `X` is a shared library, then given this code

```
Y = StaticLibrary(..., LIBS = "X")
Z = SharedLibrary(..., LIBS = "Y")
```

Is there a way to make SCons automatically notice that `Z` must link also against `X` and thus add it to the link-line automatically?

---

In our SCons buildsystem we have many different targets that each may depend on the same libraries again and again.

```
foo.a: Need bar.so
X.a: Need foo.a
Y.a: Need X.a
```

Up until a few years from now, we needed to manually specify transitive dependencies on our SConscripts to satisfy the dependencies of intermediate library files. E.g. in the above we would manually have to specify

```
 Y.a: Need X.a, need foo.a, need bar.so
```

We then changed this to sort out the dependencies automatically. For this, we simply propagated each library dependency using a recursive approach (cycles are forbidden). This works fine for Y.a.

But suppose X is a shared library. The correct dependency then needs to look like this

```
Y.a: Need X.so
```

Within X, we already encapsulated the static (and position independent) `foo.a`, and we also have prerequisite declarations (dynamic NEEDED) in `X.so` itself to resolve `bar.so` at runtime. Therefore, we must not redeclare the dependency to `bar.so` and `foo.a` here.

Ideally we would like to have SCons have this intelligence and maybe it already has, and we just haven't found it till now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCons doesn't implement this currently.

Pull requests are welcome.

You might considering bringing your current implementation to the scons users mailing list?  Perhaps it can be extended to do what you're asking and then contributed to SCons?

Comment: It won't be a fit for SCons in general. Maybe the best way forward would be a sort of global 'emitter' for the Program, StaticLibrary and SharedLibrary builders that adds dependencies to sources and LIBS of those builders?